# How much internet speed does Youtube, Twitch, etc. have?

Tags: internet, internet-connection, network-traffic

What I mean is let's say there's a live stream, and 1000 people are watching it simultaneously, and let's say each user has to download the video at 1 mb/s, does this mean that these services have internet upload speed of over 1 GB/s ?

Comment: Somewhat related: [*Can YouTube (e.g.) send a video file once and multiple users stream it?*](https://superuser.com/q/1800818/432690)

Comment: Imagine how much bandwidth was needed for yesterday's Apple iPhone 15 launch. No figures yet, but normally around 2.3 million people are watching live. that needs a lot of support, worldwide. This is done by additional servers around the world, known as CDN [content delivery network] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

Of-course if the content is popular what will likely happen is it will be distributed/cached across multiple locations so that it can be distributed more efficiently.

Strictly speaking there can also be some varience in the download speeds of each client due to buffering so there is a very small amount of wiggle room with the consistency of the speed.